# Heroku Build Rejected - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, heroku, github, build

I'm struggling to successfully execute a build on Heroku for my NodeJS app. The app works locally, when I push it to Heroku once it works great. But the subsequent pushes are being rejected by Heroku. This is what I get:

```
    Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 1.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  7.10.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.3.0
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 7.10.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 7.10.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 5.3.0 (replacing 4.2.0)...
remote:        npm 5.3.0 installed
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-07-28T16_01_18_490Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I really can't figure out what that `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` means.

EDIT: Here is the package.json (which doesn't give me any problems locally)

```
{
  "name": "truffle-init-webpack",
  "description": "Frontend example using truffle v3",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.10.0",
    "npm": "5.3.0"
  },
  "author": "Douglas von Kohorn",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "eslint": "^3.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "truffle-contract": "^1.1.6",
    "web3": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error seems to be in  your package.json. 
Refer the below link.

[Cannot read property '0' of undefined](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858)

It Seems NPM@5.3.0 is broken try downgrading to 5.2

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Next step of "Building dependencies"  is heroku starts downloading dependencies and log it. It is not present in you logs. Can you run npm install in your local directory and analysis if it is working fine.

Comment: What this .npm/_logs/2017-07-28T16_01_18_490Z-debug.log says?

Comment: Federico I am asking to many questions. Can you tell me about Git. Do you checked in your latest code?

Comment: Hey Federico, I find it some where. There are few issues in node@530 can you upgrade it and then check

Comment: I'll tell you asap

Comment: Nice catch! Super thanks! I changed 5.3.0 to 5.2.0 in package.json