# Heroku: failure to compile node.js in dependecies

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment

So i have tried to figure this out and i am having the hardest time understanding why its failing? I have tried a few of the methods online and I have `node_modules` in my `.gitignore` so I don't really understand why its broken.

I have also tried

```
git push -f heroku master
```

This failed to work as well although it should be forcing it to work. So it doesn't make very much sense to me.

[This is the terminal response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmtDa.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error "`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`" looks like [npm/npm issue 17858](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858)

It requires an update:

> I confirm that npm@latest does the trick for me:

```
node 9.2.0
npm 5.6.0
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377955/heroku-build-rejected-nodejs#comment77720441_45378111 as an example of upgrade.

Comment: I will try this